# Getting Error: Element type is invalid: error while upgrading Next.js from version 7 to 9.3

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Here's the error that I am getting when upgraded existing working application to NextJs:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (<path to project directory>\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3743:17)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (<path to project directory>\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3373:29)
    at renderToString (<path to project directory>\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3988:27)
    at render (<path to project directory>\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\render.js:82:16)
    at Object.renderPage (<path to project directory>\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\render.js:382:16)
    at Function.getInitialProps (<path to project directory>\.next\server\static\development\pages\_document.js:483:19)
```

Existing application has custom _document.js. However, even after removing that still getting above error. (Above error is after removing custome _document.js). Cannot share application code here. However, following is the code snippet from `.next\server\static\development\pages\_document.js` file around line 483. Line number 483 in above error is `await ctx.renderPage(` line in following code.

```
static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
const enhancers =  false ? undefined : [];

const enhanceApp = App => {
  for (const enhancer of enhancers) {
    App = enhancer(App);
  }

  return props => _react.default.createElement(App, props);
};

const {
  html,
  head
} = await ctx.renderPage({
  enhanceApp
});
const styles = [...(0, _server.default)(), ...( false ? undefined : [])];
return {
  html,
  head,
  styles
};
```

}

What did I try so far:

1. Googled for error
2. Tried to change import statements and commenting out portions of custom _document.js
3. Tried copying custom _document.js file example from NextJs documentation site
4. Removed custom _document.js
5. Deleted node_modules directory and ran `npm install` again
6. Deleted .next directory and restarted application again

Has anyone come across similar error? Thank you for your help. Any hint or clue also appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

After spending lot of time commenting out and figuring out where 'import' is not correctly defined, found out the newer version of next-seo package needed named import rather than default for NextSeo. I had to go through lot of files to narrow down the code in error.

Wish there was better stack trace, especially when error it was showing was from _document.js !